# Is there a way to use reflection to extract fields and build a tuple in unapply function?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am trying to model json for message passing.
Here is json example:

```
// message1
{ 
  "messageType" : "JoinChannelCommand",
  "content" : {
    "channelId" : "abc"
  }
} 

// message 2
{
  "messageType" : "SyncCommand",
  "content" : {
     "updatedAfter" : 1516726583
  }
}
```

Below is classes representing above json

```
case class JoinChannelCommand(channelId: String)
object JoinChannelCommand {
    def unapply(js: JsValue) = {
      (js \ "messageType").asOpt[String].flatMap { messageType =>
        val className = this.getClass.getSimpleName.stripSuffix("$")

    if (messageType == className) {
      (js \ "content" \ "channelId").asOpt[String]
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}

case class SyncCommand(updateAfter: Timestamp)
object SyncCommand {
    def unapply(js: JsValue) = {
      (js \ "messageType").asOpt[String].flatMap { messageType =>
        val className = this.getClass.getSimpleName.stripSuffix("$")

        if (messageType == className) {
          (js \ "content" \ "updatedAfter").asOpt[Long].map(new Timestamp(_))

        } else {
          None
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So that, I can user pattern match in this way

```
x matchs {
  case JoinChannelCommand(channelId) =>
  case SyncCommand(updatedAfter) =>
}
```

As you can see, there are a lots of boilerplate code.
I wonder if there is a way to examine fields at runtime (maybe like reflection), then to build a tuple which is used in the unapply function.

Then I just need to write:

```
trait MagicCommand {
  def unapply(js: JsValue) = { // <- where magic happened
  }
}
case class JoinChannelCommand(channelId: String)
object JoinChannelCommand extends MagicCommand
```

It will be much more convenient when the amount of commands goes large.

Answer (score 0):

With uPickle, see the last example [here](http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle/#CustomKeys) in the CustomKeys section. Basically, it adds a `$type` field in the JSON object when encoding, and uses that field to map to the appropriate case class.

Alternatively, if you spread the commands over specific REST request handlers, (and optionally eliminate the `messageType` and `content` encapsulations) validations using [play json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Validation-with-Reads) `validate` macro becomes easier.

for instance;

```
case class JoinChannelCommand(channelId: String)
object JoinChannelCommand {
     implicit lazy val joinChannelCommandFormat = Json.format[JoinChannelFormat]
}
```

assuming you are POSTing to the following controller method

```
def joinChannelHandler = Action.async(parse.default) { implicit request =>
      val joinChannelCommandOpt: Option[JoinChannelCommand] = request.body.asJson.get.validate[JoinChannelCommand].asOpt
      joinChannelCommandOpt match {
           case None => ....
           case Some(c: JoinChannelCommand) => ....
      }
      ...
}
```

It is as lean as it looks. Fully automatic. If your case classes contain `Option` fields, the resulting encoded json will not have those whenever the optional field value is `None`. This is very similar to the JS way of handling JSON stuff.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help, I am still not quite sure how to use uPickle in unapply function at first glance.
For the alternative solution, the reason I cannot use this way is because I pass those commands via socket.
I cannot predict the type of command at compile time.
I will check play's json lib and uPickle to see how to extract class fields at run time first. 
Thank you again!